# How do I override Bootstrap font?

Tags: html, css, web

I am currently working on developing an HTML and I am using Bootstrap to make it more mobile-friendly. However, the bootstrap font sucks and I am looking to override it and replace it with a better looking font. I am posting the head of my HTML file. It looks like this:

```
<head>
  <title> Connotate Engineering </title>
  <meta name=viewport content='width=700'>   
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ConnotateEngineering.css">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel="stylesheet">

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

And this is what my CSS looks like:

```
body{
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 12px;
}

#images{
  font-family: 'Arial';
  text-align:left;
  font-style: regular;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  word-spacing: 0;
}

#images a{
  margin:0px 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  font-family: 'Arial', serif;
  }

.caption {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  #sidebar { display: none;}
}
```

Comment: Use the keyword !important on font-family.

Comment: like just add it before font-family?

Comment: For example, if you want to make sure that the font is always arial do: font-family: 'Arial' !important;

Answer (score 11):

Change the link positions in your `<head>` from this:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ConnotateEngineering.css">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To this:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ConnotateEngineering.css">
```

The order matters, you want your final changes to be below all others.

And as Arham pointed out, if you put in an inline style, it will have a higher priority than the bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the whole page to have that font then you should either remove all font rules in all elements then add `body { font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive; }` or include all elements you want to have that font like:

```
body, #images, #images a {
   font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

Comment: Only the captions are changing. I want to change the h1 and h2 tags

Comment: You will have to remove the font set for each tag, or add more elements to the original code, like: `body, #images, #images a, h1, h2, h3, h4...`

Comment: I did try h1, h2{font-family: Arial}; it did not work

Comment: In that case add `!important` after the font name like `Arial !important` tho I think the font you want is 'Indie Flower'  and not Arial, am I right?

Comment: Got it. I was just trying different fonts but this worked out. Thank you

Answer (score -3):

One way is to add the style attributes within the desired tag itself.

ie: (you want to override a certain style on a div)

`<div style = "font-family: Arial">`

Comment: I strongly advise against inline styles for maintainability reasons.